# Telegram Desktop segfaulting at startup on Debian buster using Gnome 3

Tags: debian

After a reinstall of Debian buster (amd64) using telegram-desktop from the repositories, it segfaults at startup producing this output in syslog:

```
kernel: [  561.008751] telegram-deskto[3858]: segfault at 114 ip 00007f1729d8c75c sp 00007ffcac131230 error 6 in libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.31[7f1729d3e000+af000]
```

These error messages appear in the shell:

```
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new_with_properties: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplay'
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(telegram-desktop:6324): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new_with_properties: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
fish: “telegram-desktop” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

The recommendations from the debian bugtracking system (installing libindicator etc.) do not work.
However, starting telegram desktop setting `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=NONE` works. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you filed a bug report with the package maintainer for your distribution, especially having since found that the official package works?

Comment: Yes it's done: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=887010

Answer (score 1):

Switching from the package maintainer version in the debian repository to the official telegram desktop application did the trick. The version in the repository just seems to be too old.